# "The type 'string' must be a non-nullable and generic method"

Tags: c#, generics, methods

I have few questions in the following method. Can an expert help me to understand the structure and why I am getting the error?

I have this method that will get a xml element, search the attribute specified in name parameter and case is can't find in the xml, it returns the default value:

```
protected static T GetValue<T>(XElement group, string name, T default)     where T : struct
{
            //Removed some code for better view
            XAttribute setting = group.Attribute(name);
            return setting == null ? default: (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), setting.Value);
}
```

My questions is about the generic types used in this method. When I try to use this method in a string variable, I get the following error:

> string test = GetValue(element, "search", "default value");
>       The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'GetValue(XElement, string, T)'

What T is this method it the issue that I am getting that error? What does where T : struct mean? I tried to use this as GetValue and it did not work as well...

Any help are really welcome! Thanks!

Comment: `where T : struct` string is not a struct

Comment: `string` is not a `struct`.  It looks like that method is meant to only be used with enums.  For what you want just do `string text = (string)element.Attribute("search") ?? "default value";`

Comment: You should read something about constraints, for example here [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: @Rahul Yeah, sometimes I go overboard with my comments.

Comment: @thehennyy Thanks for this! I hadn't no idea the name of that. I will read more about that! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The `where T : struct` is a constraint on the generic type `T` meaning it must be a `struct`.  Since `string` is not a `struct` and you're passing a `string`, i.e. `"default value"`, you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

`string` is not a `struct` per the generic constraint `where T : struct`. It looks like that method is meant to only be used with enums based on the use of `Enum.Parse`. For what you want just do

```
string text = (string)element.Attribute("search") ?? "default value";
```

You can do something similar with most values types as well

```
int value = (int?)element.Attribute("intAttribute") ?? -1;
```

Check out the [`XAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6) documentation for which types it can be explicitly cast to.

However this doesn't work for converting to an enum, which is likely why that method was written.